# Count property values of javascript object

Tags: json, object, properties, count

I have an javascript object, which I´m getting from database via json. Is there any easy way how to count values based on the same month? (color isn´t important). So the results will be something like this:

```
data = [
{
    "value": 30,
    "month": 8,
    "color": "#49e630"
},
{
    "value": 50,
    "month": 7,
    "color": "#5001dc"
},
{
    "value": 100,
    "month": 7,
    "color": "#6365c3"
}
]

result = [
{
    "value": 30,
    "month": 8,
    "color": "#49e630"
},
{
    "value": 150,
    "month": 7,
    "color": "#6365c3"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a map based on the month value, like so:

```
//populate a map with keys based on the month
var monthMap = new Object();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (monthMap[data[i]['month']] == null) {
        monthMap[data[i]['month']] = data[i];
    } else {
        monthMap[data[i]['month']]['value'] += data[i]['value'];
    }
}

//convert monthMap to list
var result = [];
for (var key in monthMap) {
    if (monthMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result.push(monthMap[key]);
    }
}
```

Edit: you could also write the data loop like this, which may be slightly more legible:

```
//populate a map with keys based on the month
var monthMap = new Object();
data.forEach(function(listitem) {

    var month = listitem['month'];

    if (monthMap[month] == null) {
        monthMap[month] = listitem;
    } else {
        monthMap[month]['value'] += listitem['value'];
    }
});

//convert to list...
```

Comment: Glad to help! I would appreciate it if you could mark this answer as accepted when you get the chance. Thanks!